# Tazria-Metsora Parsha Riddle

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, riddle

You might see me but i don't affect you yet, I come in all shapes and sizes, and i stopped the B'nai Yisroel in the desert for a week. ??????Who am I???????

Answer (score 2):

Tzaraas!!!!!!!!

Comment: Awright WAYON! Or was this planned?

Comment: it wasnt, even ask shlomo.